# Printing with Outlook.com?

Tags: outlook.com, printing

With the Outlook.com, I cannot print. I do not have the Action button, nor the three dots. All I can do is a print screen, which is less than ideal for long emails and because of all the unseemly stuff on the right hand side.

Any suggestions on how to print and/or how to get the Action or ... options made avail to me. I am using FireFox.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how you've managed to get rid of all your function buttons, but you could try the shortcut <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> to print.

Answer (score -2):

Control print does not print the messages, only the message titles

Comment: Is this an answer to the question? The asker wants to know how to print. And what is "Control print"? Do you mean "Control + P"?